# How to snap edges to some other edges?

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

Consider the following:
[image]

I want to snap the edges of that smaller part to the edges of the bigger part:

[image]

Using the snapping tool will let me do this, but will change the shape of the whole part. I could also just move the part into position, yes, but I am hoping for a better solution. I can also use the proportional editing tool to move the whole part by moving a single vertex, however then the snapping tool does not work.

Is there perhaps a way to move the whole part when only moving one edge/vertex, and still be able to snap to other edges, or some other way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do it (Not sure if it's the best way).

Having all of the faces of the part selected,
[image]

but making sure the snap tool is set to vertex snap mode (NOT face snap):

[image]

and pressing G and moving the part to the appropriate position, will work:

[image]